# How to put a time for a command to apply

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to show something then make it disabbear but the commands don't work out I already tried invoke and IEnumerator

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). currently, it is absolutely not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to phrase your question "correctly"! What does that mean?

- Preferably **google your question first**, because this is a very simple, googleable question
- Provide **as much information as necessary**
- Tell us **what exactly isn't working**
- Show us **what you tried already** (**include the code**)

About your initial question:

You can delay something with several ways. You could either use a [**coroutine**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) with [**WaitForSeconds**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html), an async operation or a timer. I linked two valuable sources about **coroutines** and the **WaitForSeconds** class from Unity's official documentation in the previous sentence.

Example:

```cs
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitToExecute()); // This will call the coroutine
}

private IEnumerator WaitToExecute()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(12); // This will wait 12 seconds
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

Notes:

- You need to call a coroutine using [StartCoroutine(NameOfCoroutine());](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) (it is also possible with a string as the parameter, but try to avoid that.
- If your Time Scale is not set to 1, you might want to use [WaitForSecondsRealtime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html).
- If you are using a loop in your coroutine and the amount of seconds you want to wait between each iteration is the same, you should store the WaitForSeconds instance in a variable to avoid unnecessary memory allocation.